# Creating a dictionary in C# from a text file with a defined structure

Tags: c#

I have a text file with this info in it:

```
01 Index
home
about

02 Home
first
second
third
```

The line that starts with a number signifies a key and following it, till a blank line, are the values.

I want to have a Dictionary object with the key as the first line and the lines following it till the blank line as a string array representing.

Like so:

```
key = "01 Index"
value = string[]
```

where the values in the array would be:

```
string[0] = "home"
string[1] = "about"
```

The next key would be "02 Home" and its following lines as string[].

This method reads the text file:

```
string[] ReadFileEntries(string path)
{
   return File.ReadAllLines(path);
}
```

This gives all the lines, 8 in the sample above, in the string[] where the 4th line would be the blank line.

How do I create the required dictionary from this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: What errors do you have ?

Comment: There are no errors, I am stuck after the ReadFileEntries method.

Comment: Don't understand why this is being marked for close???

Comment: Usually we like it when the "asker" attempts it on his own before posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

To parse the file into, say, `Dictionary<String, String[]>` you can do somthing like that:

```
  Dictionary<String, String[]> data = new Dictionary<String, String[]>();

  String key = null;
  List<String> values = new List<String>();

  foreach (String line in File.ReadLines(path)) {
    // Skip blank lines
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
      continue; 

    // Check if it's a key (that should start from digit)
    if ((line[0] >= '0' && line[0] <= '9')) { // <- Or use regular expression
      if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, key))
        data.Add(key, values.ToArray());

        key = line;
        values.Clear();

        continue;
    }

    // it's a value (not a blank line and not a key)
    values.Add(line);
  }

  if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, key))
    data.Add(key, values.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're wanting to do. There is room for improvement, and I suggest refactoring a bit.

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

var input = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
var currentValue = new List<string>();
var currentKey = string.Empty;

foreach (var line in input)
{
    if (currentKey == string.Empty)
    {
        currentKey = line;
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        currentValue.Add(line);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        result.Add(currentKey, currentValue.ToArray());
        currentKey = string.Empty;
        currentValue = new List<string>();
    }
}

if (currentKey != string.Empty)
{
    result.Add(currentKey, currentValue.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We declare a dictionary of that nature in this manner:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
```

To populate it we do this:

```
myDict.Add(someString, someStringArray[]);
```

I think something like this would do it:

```
string[] TheFileAsAnArray = ReadFileEntries(path);
Dictionary<string, string[]> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()

string key = "";
List<string> values = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i <= TheFileAsAnArray.Length; i++)
{

    if(String.isNullOrEmpty(TheFileAsAnArray[i].Trim()))
    {
          myDict.Add(key, values.ToArray());
          key = String.Empty;
          values = new List<string>();

    }
    else
    {
        if(key == String.Empty)
            key = TheFileAsAnArray[i];
        else
            values.Add(TheFileAsAnArray[i]);
    }
}
```